# SSIS - looping through xml files with complex datatype

Tags: xml, ssis, complextype

I am having problems with looping through xml files with complex datatype. When i am using ForEach Loop Container and Data Flow Task inside with XML Source i get an error message:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Does anyone encountered similar problem? Maybe there are any know solutions on the web? I can't find any.
I can add that i have SSIS package that allows me for parsing single xml complex type but i can't put those files into the loop:(
Any ideas?
Regards

Comment: The loop should be treating each file individually, so its strange that single iteration would work but not when looped. Have you looked at maybe using SQL's built in XML parser, so SSIS then feeds the XML as a string to a SQL xml datatype, you can then read the xml in SQL as if it was a table. Even output multiple rows if xml is an array

Comment: Thank you for answer. To parse single xml file i used XML Task, to parse few i tried to use ForEach Loop Container + XML Source and in this case XML Source is giving me a headache:(